# найти в каком комите и файле присутствовал такой текст последний раз

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

**Данно:**

- в репозиторие кто то когда то создал метод getCleanProduct в какомто файле.
- через неизвестное количество коммитов удалили этот метод.

**Задача:**

- найти в каком коммите создали этот метод и в коком файле
- найти все коммиты манипуляции с методом
- найти коммит где удаляли метод

**Проблема:**

Создали метод getCleanProduct, использовали его в разных местах, потом кто то удалил этот метод, а уже через полгода выявилась бага в котором вызывается несуществующий метод. Нужно востановить его, разобраться почему удалили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самый простой способ (есть способы и получше, но язык не указан, поэтому грусть-печаль)

```
git log -S 'void getCleanProduct'
```

имя попробуйте максимально правильно указать. В результате покажет все диффы, где есть эта строка.

`git log` выведет обычный лог, что бы посмотреть диффы для каждой нужной стороки - используйте `git show <sha>`.

Также есть такая штука

```
git log -L :имя_функции:имя_файла
```

она покажет все изменения, которые были с указанной функцией (в вопросе звучит "метод", видимо это джава. С с и плюсами git хорошо работает, с остальными можно обучить, как правильно искать границы функции).

Comment: git log -S 'void getCleanProduct' выведет мне комиты, но просматривать  diff нереально большой обьем, может есть какойто фильтр который указал бы на файл

Comment: А Вы уже пробовали? Если строка-фильтр задана верно, то дифов будет не так и много (по идее всего два - один на добавление, один на удаление).

В целом, есть ещё параметр --name-only, который покажет измененные в коммите файлы.

Comment: отлично, команда `git log -S 'void getCleanProduct' -p --name-only`